# keyboard-setup.service very slow on Ubuntu 16.10 (Lenovo z50-70)

Tags: boot, keyboard

I have a slow boot and I ran systemd-analyze plot to see the causes. I noticed that keyboard-setup.service last 5.946 seconds!

I have Ubuntu 16.10 (but had this problem on 16.04, too) and a Lenovo z50-70 with italian layout keyboard. How can I resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted the laptop. Clicked the system setting, then universal setting.There is column typing. There I set key response short by sliding the indicator. This worked for me.